# What does the term `requests` in `requests_per_second` actually mean?

Tags: elasticsearch

In [Delete By Query API doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-delete-by-query.html#docs-delete-by-query-throttle), **Throttling delete requests** section

> To control the rate at which delete by query issues **batches** of delete operations, you can set **requests_per_second** to any positive decimal number. This pads each batch with a wait time to throttle the rate. Set requests_per_second to -1 to disable throttling.

> Throttling uses a wait time **between batches so that the internal scroll requests** can be given a timeout that takes the request padding into account. The padding time is the difference between the batch size divided by the requests_per_second and the time spent writing. By default the batch size is 1000, so if requests_per_second is set to 500:

```
target_time = 1000 / 500 per second = 2 seconds
wait_time = target_time - write_time = 2 seconds - .5 seconds = 1.5 seconds
```

**Q1:** From the above example, it seems that the wording `requests` within `requests_per_second` indicates the documents in ES index, not the **internal scroll/batch requests**, that is this parameter indeed control how many docs to handle per second, right? If so, I think `docs_per_second` might be a better name.

> Since the batch is issued as a single _bulk request, large batch sizes cause Elasticsearch to create many requests and wait before starting the next set. This is "bursty" instead of "smooth".

**Q2:** I do not understand well why the batch is issued as a single _bulk request?

Answer (score -1):

**Q1:** No actually it `scroll_size` which determine batch size for scrolling results used by the `_delete_by_query` method

**Q2:** The batch size here is the size of `DELETE` queries which was generated by the batch_size setup in the `_search` generate by the `_delete_by_query` / `scroll_size` sent to `_bulk` function to delete documents, so every batch selected are sent to delete in 1 `_bulk`